# Product = Sum Sudoku (Royal Statistical Society Christmas Quiz 2023)

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

[image: 6 x 6 Sudoku puzzle subdivided into 2 x 3 sub-grids]

Normal Sudoku rules for this grid size apply.  The product of the numbers on each pink diagonal equals the sum of the numbers in the blue square.

---

This puzzle is from the now closed contest at: https://rss.org.uk/RSS/media/File-library/Quiz/RSS-Christmas-Quiz-2023-R2.pdf

Comment: Is there supposed to be a fairly short and straightforward solution path to this??

Comment: Up to a certain point It seems you are just brute forcing values until one fits.

Comment: @PDT I am not sure if there is a simple solution to this puzzle.  I decided to post this puzzle because it seemed elegant to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic number is:

> 30

Solution:

> [image]

Comment: I got the answer too but I can’t seem to find a simple enough solution path that what is difficult

Comment: Answers to [grid-deduction] puzzles on this site are generally expected to share at least part of their solve path. Can you [edit] in some key deductions? For example, how you determined the magic number.

Comment: @Bobble this puzzle is really difficult the only way I can see solving it is after finding out some possible values for the diagonals inferring values on the bottom three blue squares and then just trying out different permutations, see their refutations until one fits…

Comment: The diagonals can only be 30,32 and 36 in size the 32 because of the 442 configuration is easy to refute but the 36 configurations has a lot of different variations that you have to refute. Then you are left with the 30 and again there are a ton of refutations!!!

Comment: Some grid deductions are just not meant for PSE or where one is expected to give a thorough and concise step by step solution path…